# Reference request for an elementary identity in cardinal arithmetic

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, cardinal-arithmetic

Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal. Then we have

$$\beth_{\kappa+1} = \prod_{\alpha<\kappa} \beth_{\alpha} = \beth_{\kappa}^{\kappa}$$

The only non-trivial inequality is the first less-than-or-equal-to which can be obtained by coding each $X \in \mathcal{P}(\beth_{\kappa}) \cong \beth_{\kappa+1}$ as the map $f \in \prod_{\alpha<\kappa} \beth_{\alpha}$ defined by $f(\alpha)=g_{\alpha}(X \cap \beth_{\alpha-1})$ for non-zero non-limit $\alpha$, where $g_{\alpha}: \mathcal{P}(\beth_{\alpha-1})\rightarrow \beth_{\alpha}$ is a fixed bijection, and $f(\alpha)=0$ for other $\alpha$.

I need to use this identity in a manuscript (intended for non-set theorists) and want to avoid including a full proof to save space. Does anyone know of any textbook which contains this as a fact? The closest one I was able to find is Exercise I.13.33 in Kunen's (new) book which only covers the case $\kappa=\omega$. (Worst case, I'll write down the proof myself but given Kunen's exercise, this product shouldn't be that unusual and must have been written down somewhere...)

Comment: This does not seem correct to me. For many $\kappa$, we have $\beth_\kappa^\kappa=\beth_\kappa$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: The cofinality of $\beth_\kappa$ is the cofinality of $\kappa$. So that can't be right.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: $\beth_{\kappa}^{\kappa} \leq \left(2^{\beth_{\kappa}}\right)^{\kappa} = 2^{\beth_{\kappa} \cdot \kappa}=2^{\beth_{\kappa}}=\beth_{\kappa+1} \leq \prod_{\alpha < \kappa}...$. So the result should hold if I am not making some obvious mistake with the inequality that I explained.

Comment: Ah, $\beth_\kappa\ne\beth_{\kappa+1}$ :-) Oops.

Comment: Now that I see my foolishness, this is really quite close to the manipulations involved in the combinatorial proofs of Silver's theorem (a quick argument as you suggest is in the chapter on COmbinatorics by Kunen in the Handbook of Mathematical Logic). Maybe look at the Galvin-Hajnal paper, or the book on the partition calculus by Erdős et al.

Comment: By the way, "non-zero non-limit $\alpha$" is just "a successor $\alpha$", or even "$\alpha=\beta+1$".

Comment: Look in Jech’s book, chapter called something like “axiom of choice and cardinal arithmetic”